# Set the picture of a imageview loading it from an arraylist of bitmaps

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap, imageview

I have an arraylist of bitmaps and I need to print the images in some imageviews. I fill the arraylist loading the pictures from the sdcard of my phone and I try to print it but the imageview doesn't show any picture.

The code of my activity is the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
public static int seleccionado=0;
private GridView gridview;
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    imagenes=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    String[] imgColumnID = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imgColumnID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
    new String[] { "%sdcard%" }, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String result=cursor.getString(0);
            byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(result,Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            imagenes.add(bitmap);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.e("ima", String.valueOf(imagenes.size()));
    gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new AdapterImagenes(this));
    gridview.setSelection(seleccionado);
}
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new AdapterImagenes(this));
    gridview.setSelection(seleccionado);
}
public class AdapterImagenes extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context contexto;
    public AdapterImagenes(Context c){
        contexto=c;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return imagenes.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return 0;
    }
     @SuppressLint("NewApi") public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
         ImageView imageView;
         if(convertView==null){  
                imageView=new ImageView(contexto);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 130));
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setCropToPadding(true);
                }else{
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                }
                imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
         }else{
             imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
         }
         imageView.setImageBitmap(imagenes.get(position));
         imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                 seleccionado=(Integer)v.getTag();
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                 String index=String.valueOf(position);
                 Bundle extras=new Bundle();
                 extras.putString("position", index);
                 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerFotos.class).putExtras(extras).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
             }
         });
         try{
             imageView.setTag(position);
             if(position==seleccionado){
                 imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff6203"));
             }else{
                 imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
             }
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
         }
         return imageView;
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Any error are you getting??

Comment: No, anything. The imageviews are creating but it hasn't any content.

Comment: I think the problem is, that You haven´t inflated the layout. See this example http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: I inflate the layout and the problem persist.

Comment: Actually your code should get the outofmemoryerror coz lots of bitmaps in arraylist.. your approach is wrong